# Adding Navigationbar to MoviePlayer

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am trying to find out what I can do with an iPad as far as playing back video is concerned.  And I have the following code for a UIButton action.

```
- (IBAction)playClick:(id)sender {
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
NSString *moviePath = [bundle pathForResource:@"video3" ofType:@"m4v"];
NSURL  *movieURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:moviePath];
MPMoviePlayerController *theMovie = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];
theMovie.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFill;
[theMovie play];
MPMoviePlayerViewController *moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];
[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:moviePlayer];
}
```

[image: video]

As shown above, I do get a movie screen.  I wonder if it's possible to include a navigation bar at the top (above 'Done') or the bottom (below the controller) of the movie screen so that I can add some actions while the user plays back video?  I guess [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6677333/iphone-add-button-on-mpmovieplayerviewcontrollers-navigation-bar) may concern what I'm trying to do.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: the navigation bar is already there right!!do you mean that you need to add more button items??

Answer (score 0):

You can add more buttons using,

```
UIBarButtonItem *button = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(yourButtonAction:)]; 
moviePlayer.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = button;
```

Customize these buttons as per your need.

Try this .Hope that make sense.

regards

Comment: Thanks.  In fact, I have tried that, following tips available with 'this topic.'  But a button besides Done never appears.

Comment: I guess the following web site has an example with sharedApplication.  http://sugartin.info/2011/09/07/creating-customized-movieplayer-in-iphone-ipad-both/